# Prove that the probability that $x+y\leq 1,$ given that $x^2+y^2\geq \frac{1}{4}$ is $\frac{8-\pi}{16-\pi}$.

Tags: probability

Let $2$ positive real numbers $x,y$ satisfy $x\leq 1,y\leq 1$ are chosen at random.Prove that the probability that $x+y\leq 1,$ given that $x^2+y^2\geq \frac{1}{4}$ is $\frac{8-\pi}{16-\pi}$.

Since the $x+y\leq 1$ and $x^2+y^2\geq \frac{1}{4}$,so the required probability is area outside circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$,centered at $(0,0)$ and inside the line segment whose $x-$intercept and $y-$intercept are 1 each in the first quadrant.so probability$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{16}=\frac{8-\pi}{16}$

But my answer does not match the given answer.Somewhere i must have faltered,Can you please guide me to the right method?

Comment: because a conditional probability is required you must divide your answer $A$ by the measure of the sample space - this is not the full square, but  $A+\frac12$ (i.e. omitting the 'forbidden' area inside the circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the conditional probability you need to divide by the "given" area.

in this case $ Area(x^2+y^2 \ge \frac 14)=1-\frac{\pi}{16}$